# Why is it impossible to determine number of visible emission spectrum of He+

Tags: physical-chemistry, atomic-structure

We know that atoms emit spectral lines on excitation and de excitation.

I was doing one high school question based on this theory

> Number of visible lines when an electron returns from 5th orbit upto ground state in a sample of He+ ions

Answer was "Cannot be determined"

But I think it cannot be, as we know that Balmer series of hydrogen transitions are in visible side so we can calculate same wavelength emission in case of helium atom too.

Example: 3 to 2 transition in hydrogen lies in visible region... So same wavelength emission will be emitted in helium in the transition 6 to 4 using Rydberg formula. So how is the answer "cannot be determined"? If it can be then am I correct

Comment: Here you go: https://laserstars.org/spectra/ProtoHydrogen.html. Seems to be called the Pickering series. Looks like you were right. (+1)

Comment: @EdV So should the answer be 1 line? Because then only  5 to 4 transition should be considered having visible wavelength

Comment: @EdV 4-7 (5412 Å) , 4-9 (4522 Å) ,4-6 (6560 Å) and 4-8 (4859 Å) these four? but from 5 to 1 transition none of these are obtained.

Comment: @EdV My query is : how many visible transitions are there from 5th orbit to ground (1st) orbit? 1,2,3 or what?

Comment: I think the answer that was given is based on this. If the electron drop directly from 5 to 1, then 1 UV photon is emitted. But if the electron drops in cascade fashion, from 5 to 4, then 4 to 3, then 3 to 2 or 1, then you get 1 IR photon, 1 visible photon, and 1 or 2 UV photons. This looks more like a trick question than anything else. Anyway, I will comment no further.